# Datepicker not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker for my active admin. I upgraded my app from rails 4.6 to rails 5 then my app started to fail.

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript'
```

I added gem `'jquery-ui-rails'` gem and added `//= require jquery-ui` in application.js and  `*= require jquery-ui` but still my problem didn't solved.

```
application.js
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

and restart your server

Update:

Rearrange your js as following and restart your server.

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: can u please past your application.js?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please find application.js above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your 'active_admin_datetimepicker', so try to update your Gemfile with:

gem 'active_admin_datetimepicker', '=0.6.3'